# Do viewWillDisappear / viewDidDisappear get called when switching apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering if `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` get called when iOS switches apps (for example, the Home button gets pressed by the user). This would cause the view to disappear from the screen, but do the callbacks get called for this?

Comment: And what are the results of your testing?

Comment: I'm sure there are folks who have wondered about this. Googling is still faster than coding up a test project.

Comment: app delegates only get called during app switching.

Answer (score 27):

You can.

The solution - which I have used before - is to use the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground:` in your app delegate.

Do this in your app delegate.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self.window.rootViewController beginAppearanceTransition:NO animated:NO];
    [self.window.rootViewController endAppearanceTransition];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self.window.rootViewController beginAppearanceTransition:YES animated:NO];
    [self.window.rootViewController endAppearanceTransition];
}
```

Now your `viewWillDisappear:`, `viewDidDisappear:`, `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` methods of your view controller hierarchy will get called when you app goes to background and back to foreground.

Hope this works?

---

Edit 24/11/16 (Swift 3 version)

```swift
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    window?.rootViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: false)
    window?.rootViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
}
   
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    window?.rootViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
    window?.rootViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
}
```

---

Edit 2/1/2017 (all windows)

```swift
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    for window in application.windows {
        window.rootViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: false)
        window.rootViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
    }
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    for window in application.windows {
        window.rootViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
        window.rootViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems amazingly simply. But are there any (nasty) side effects for doing this?

Comment: Unless you do something crazy like putting initializating code in any `viewWillAppear:` or likewise destructor code in `viewWillDisappear:`, I don't see this causing any troubles. I've experienced none so far.

Comment: I've added code to show how to trigger the calls on all application windows. This should be the only drawback of the first - it only works on the main window.

Comment: For some reason these lifecycle methods are not being called in my case. Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Why does not Apple implement this under the hood? Too much open space left for developers, which forces them to come up with such hacky workarounds.

Answer (score 22):

Nope, those methods won't be called in that case.

To be notified when the app goes into the background, you can register for the UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification notification.

As an aside, the easiest way find out this kind of thing is to just build a super simple app quick and set breakpoints.